# Perfect forwarding of primitive types

Tags: c++, move, rvalue-reference, primitive-types, perfect-forwarding

I need to implement some methods similar to `vector::emplace` for my own data structures. In the general case, I would implement them so that they support perfect forwarding, i.e., with rvalue-references, `std::forward` and that stuff.

However, what if I know that all parameters to forward are primitive types such as `int` or `float`. Does it make any sense to implement perfect forwarding for primitive types?

In other words, is there a difference between the following two code snippets, assuming that we only use primitive types as template parameters?

```
template <typename... Args>
void wrapper(Args&& ... args) {
   func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

and

```
template <typename... Args>
void wrapper(Args ... args) {
   func(args...);
}
```

Additionally: Is there any difference if we know that the template parameters can only be classes which contain only primitive types? Or classes that contains only primitive types and other classes which themselves contain only primitive types?

Comment: Your "additionally" question makes no sense. Ignoring the allocator, a simple `vector` implementation contains only three pointers. Presumably you mean something about PODs or the like?

Comment: I don't see what the implementation of `std::vector` has do to with my question. Basically, question has nothing to do with vectors at all. The "additional" question is simply: Is there a difference between both pieces of code, assuming all template parameters are structs/classes which contain only primitive types as members.

Comment: A vector contains three pointers, pointers are primitive types, so it's a "class which contain only primitive types", but obviously you'd want to perfectly forward a vector.

Comment: As far as I know, primitive types usually denote char, int, float etc., but not pointers or references. See e.g. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa712840%28v=vs.71%29.aspx. The C++ standard does not know the term "primitive type".

Comment: Well, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_data_type#Overview) pointers and references are included. Regardless, a class' constructors and destructor can do arbitrarily complex things even if the class has only `int` data members.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it absolutely does not make any sense to use perfect forwarding for basic types:

1. Copying is equivalent to moving them.
2. Copying them costs about the same or less (due to other optimizations and especially pointer-aliasing) than passing by reference.
3. The best code is code that is not there.

There is one exception though:
There is no way to avoid taking output-parameters by reference.

Also, if you are writing a template anyway, are you absolutely sure you will never want to use it with more complex types?
YAGNI (You ain't gonna need it) is very important, but not handicapping yourself later by unneccessarily restricting your interface is too.

And always remember the old adage "Premature optimization is the root of all evil".

Comment: Depends on whether `func` might take something by reference, no?

Comment: @T.C.: You mean output-parameters?

Comment: As I understand your answer, it is also valid in the cases I described at the end of my question, right?

Comment: @user1494080: Yes, and the additional copies can probably optimized away in that case anyway. If not, for large types not copying might be a bit more efficient. Naturally, if it's actually an out-parameter, there's no choice. That presumes your types are still trivial types.